# Hair bouncing bones in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, game-physics, arkit, quaternions

I'm developing a game in SceneKit (iOS 13) and I want to add realism to the movements of the character.

The character has hair with a skeleton-bones, so I can make it bounce programmatically. I want to rotate the bones in a natural way so the hair bounces.

What's the best approach for this? As soon as there is no-movement, I want the bones to return to the original position.

Here is a reference of how bones are placed:

[image: Image does not belong to me, just using it as reference]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and surfing the web I found an example of exactly what I want to achieve, and it's called: **Inverse Kinematics**

Hope it helps anyone who wants to achieve this. Here is a GitHub repo I found by Robert-Hein Hooijmans.

https://github.com/roberthein/InverseKinematics

[image]

(I don't know why it got -1. Either I didn't explain myself correctly or people are being subjective. Yes it's a rant.) (If anyone here can tell me the reason they think it got -1, let me know!, I'm here to learn how to post)